# hibernate SQL sentences over writing catalina.out. File getting out of control !

Tags: hibernate

**UPDATE**: The answer for this question is in the comments of Martins answer

I have a this application on hibernate+spring installed on differents clients for one server. Just found out that they were compiled with the Hibernate - show_sql = true, and every time my app gets a hit it fills the catalina.out with hql. my catalina.out file is growing a lot. I need to turn this show_sql without stoping the server on production. Can this be done ?

My file is getting really big, i dont want to compile every application (have different releases by cliente), stop the server, upload, and restart.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things not perfectly clear from that question so I'll hazard a guess. You seem to be using Tomcat since you're talking about catalina.out. That means your webapps should be extracted in a webapps directory somewhere. That means you should be able to find persistence.xml or hibernate-something.xml that holds your hibernate configuration. In that file you should have a `<propery name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` or simply `<propery name="show_sql" value="true"/>`.

You can edit this file and change the value to false, but since it's likely to be cached it will only take effect after you restart your web-apps. You could do this one at a time for the affected apps or restart your tomcat service which would likely be a bit more disruptive.

Comment: Hello Martin, thank you for your answer, its true i wrote the question quiet in a hurry, you are correct im using tomcat, spring+hibernate, the thing is i cant find either the persistence.xml,nor a hibernate-something.xml, (tried find search: *hibernate*). I know i can change them before i compile the conde in the applicationContext.xml

Comment: @Ernest: Your applicationContext.xml is likely inside of one of the application jars. Even if you find it and hand-modify it, you will have to restart Tomcat. I'd go for a new build with the appropriate show_sql value.

Comment: If you say that you would change the setting in applicationContext.xml if you were to recompile the webapp, then that's obviously where the setting is located, I'm sorry to mislead you. `/var/lib/tomcat6/_name_of_webapp_/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml` is where I would have to edit the setting, and the need to restart the webapp or tomcat would still apply. The path may obviously be different for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. i got an answer of what to do now, how ever i would like to know how can i prevent this on the future, how can i have the ability to turn on and off the show_sql on excetion time. Im not sure it up to this point should i chekclick this answer like answered.

Comment: Isn't the question really, when would I ever want to have `show_sql = true` in production? I see it as a debug-setting and I guess it's fine to enable it in testing but I'd never commit code with the setting enabled into a deployment branch. It's bound to slow the app down and as you've noticed it floods the logs with SQL. Leave it off and enable in testing or those rare cases where you might actually want to see the output.

Comment: Note that you can use logger org.hibernate.SQL (need to double check) to produce sql output instead of changing hibernate config. It may be easier to manipulate at run time.